# Pourquoi le "e" se prononce [ε] dans le mot "veiller" ?

Tags: prononciation

Je comprends que le "e" se prononce [ε] dans les cas suivants :

1. avec les accents è, ê, ë
2. dans les syllabes fermées comme dans "veille"
3. devant les doubles consonnes comme dans "professeur"

Mais le mot "v**e**iller" ne correspond à aucune des règles. J'aurais même tendance à le prononcer comme [ə] puisque c'est est la dernière lettre de la première syllabe du mot, comme dans "jeter". Alors pourquoi c'est [ε] ici ?

(Je me demande si ça reprend tout simplement la prononciation du mot "veille", mais par exemple dans la paire de mots "appel -> appeler", le "e" change de prononciation quand on transforme le nom en verbe...
Je me demande aussi si ça vient du groupement "ei", mais par exemple dans le mot "travailler", le "a" n'est pas groupé avec le "i" du "ill"...)

Comment: Dans *travailler* les lettres *ai* se prononcent [aj], s'il n'y avait le *i* on prononcerait [travale]. La lettre *e* n'est pas la dernière lettre de la première syllabe du mot  de *veiller* : veil-ler. [ε] est la prononciation habituelle du groupe de lettres *ei*. Bref, je ne comprends pas la question. Je pense que tu n'as pas les bonnes références. On peut consulter : un [séparateur de syllabes](https://www.separarensilabas.com/index-fr.php), graphies du son [ɛ] : https://www.francepodcasts.com/2020/11/17/le-son-e-%C9%9B/.

Comment: Dans _travailler_, c'est la lettre _a_ qui se prononce [a], et le groupement _ill_ se prononce [j], le groupement _er_ se prononce [e], non ? Et puis si on coupe les syllabes comme veil-ler, sa prononciation devient [vεj-le] et non pas [vε-je]...

Comment: *ill* ne se prononcerait pas [j] mais [il] (comme dans illisible par exemple). Et voir trav**ail**  [trav**aj**]. *Veiller* se prononce [vɛje], il n'y a pas de rapport entre le découpage en syllabes et la prononciation.

Comment: _ill_ se prononce [j] **après une voyelle** comme dans _taille_, _caillou_ par exemple, n'est-ce pas ? (et il peut se prononcer [ij] ou [il] après une consonne, comme dans _fille_ ou _ville_)
Alors que _il_ se prononce [j] seulement quand il est **après une voyelle et en fin du mot** (comme dans _travail_). Il se prononce [il] au milieu du mot (comme dans _filet_, _bilan_) sinon [il] ou [i] après une consonne (comme dans _fil_ ou _gentil_)

Comment: Peut-être que [ceci](https://regardsurlefrancais.com/2021/04/17/comment-prononcer-le-double-l-en-francais/) te renseignera plus sur les deux L et le i.

Comment: Selon votre article, c'est bien le groupement _ill_ qui se prononce [j] comme j'ai compris... Mais bon revenons à votre premier commentaire, quand vous dites que "les lettres _ai_ se prononcent [aj]" dans _travailler_, alors que les lettres _ei_ se prononcent [ε] en tant que groupe de lettres dans _veiller_. Je voudrais savoir pourquoi les traiter différemment ? Si _ei_ forment un groupe qui se prononce [ε], pourquoi _ai_ ne se prononce pas aussi [ε] en tant que groupe ?

Comment: @Zoé une source pour l'affirmation *"e" se prononce [ε] dans le mot "veiller"* ? Cela me parait un peu trop catégorique et pourrait induire en erreur un apprenant FLE qui tomberait sur cette question...

Answer (score 3):

***Veiller*** n'est jamais prononcé /vəje/ qui correspond à ***veuillez***.

Des différences individuelles, régionales ou de registre peuvent se faire entendre. La prononciation de ***veiller*** varie entre /vεje/ et /veje/, de ***surveillant*** entre /syʁvɛjɑ̃/ et /syʁvejɑ̃/, etc.

Ce n'est pas le seul mot à pouvoir présenter cette alternance qui **me** semble tout à fait naturelle :

| [εj] | [ej] |
| --- | --- |
| appareil | appareiller |
| conseil | conseiller |
| oreille | oreiller |
| réveil | réveiller |
| sommeil | sommeiller |
| merveille | émerveiller |

C'est la place du '***eil***' dans le mot qui entraîne cette différence de prononciation, plus généralisée dans le sud de la France.

Pour *appareiller*, le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appareiller) indique:

> PRONONCIATION : [apaʀ εje], j'appareille [ʒapaʀ εj]. Le Petit Robert transcrit le mot avec [e] fermé pour la 3<sup>e</sup> syllabe du mot. Warnant (*Dictionnaire de la prononciation française*, 1968) donne les deux possibilités de prononciation. Il réserve celle avec [ε] ouvert au langage soutenu, celle avec [e] fermé au langage courant (pour la transcription avec [λ], cf. appareil).

---

Pierre Fouché, *Traité de prononciation française*, 1959 :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Mais ***accueil*** (souvent mal orthographié *<s>acceuil</s>*) se prononce /akœj/.

Comment: Ca alors, on prononcerait différement appareil et appareiller. Ca doit dépendre des régions car pour ma part, je ne vois aucune différence.

Comment: @XouDo J'ai écris *qui **me** semble* et que des différences régionales existent mais ce n'était pas suffisamment clair, j'en conviens. Je révise ma réponse. Merci.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je vois bien que le mot veiller se prononce /vεje/ ou /veje/ (comme tous les autres mot terminant par _eiller_), mais je voudrais encore chercher une règle de prononciation qui pourrait expliquer le son /ε/ (ou /e/) dans ce mot...

Comment: On ne peut pas toujours déduire la prononciation d'un mot français rien qu'à sa lecture, contrairement à d'autres langues comme l'allemand ou l'espagnol. J'ai quand même ajouté à ma réponse ces "règles" (ou plutôt observations) pour les mots en -eille et -eil.

Comment: D'accord ! En fait ce qui m'a perturbée le plus c'était la différence de prononciation entre -eille et -aille (la graphique "ei" se prononce /ε/ dans le premier cas alors que la graphique "ai", qui a dans la plupart des mots la même prononciation - /ε/ - ne se prononce pas pareillement). Ça m'arrange de considérer que ce groupe de mots en -eille et -eil ne fait pas partie des mots français dont on peut déduire la prononciation selon leur épellation :)

Comment: Pour préciser mon propos, dans les régions que je fréquente, les mots comme *appareil* sont toujours prononcés /ε/ alors que les verbes (*appareiller*) sont prononcés indifféremment /ε/ ou /e/.

Comment: @XouDo moi c'est l'inverse, j'entends rarement dire [ε] dans "appareiller" et quasi jamais dans "veiller", même chez les gens qui prononcent [ε] dans "lait" et "très". Donc j'entends toujours la différence...

Comment: Je suis avec @jlliagre les prononciations sont toujours différentes, sauf sans doute dans le sud de la France.

Comment: @Hugues J'ai pourtant un peu écrit le contraire. Dans le sud de la France, la différence est généralisée (à l'exclusion de l'accent corse avec lequel c'est la voyelle /e/ qui est utilisée dans les deux cas)..

Comment: je crois que l'on est plutôt d'accord. Il y a toujours une différence entre la prononciation d' appareil et appareiller;  sauf sans doute dans certaines régions de France, tu mentionnes la Corse et je pensais au Sud de la France (vers Carcassonne), où on a aussi /e/ dans les deux cas